# ssh port forwarding using config

Tags: ssh, openssh, port-forwarding

On a box the command line has been disabled and the ssh prompt is not accessible.

What is the equivalent of:

```
ssh> -L 8001:192.168.122.4:80
```

Port forwarding needs to be set up so that a host connecting to the current host on port 8001 will have all traffic sent to 192.168.122.4:80 (accessible over a bridged adapter).

Stuff tried:

```
S vim ~/.ssh/config
Host 10.10.10.109
    User dave
    LocalForward 8001 192.168.122.4:80
```